# How can I use a CASE statement in a WHERE clause with IS NULL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Here's my queries, they don't work but I want to do something like this :

```
SELECT a_field FROM a_table
WHERE
... 
AND
CASE
WHEN a_value_from_another_query IS NULL THEN a_second_field IS NULL
ELSE a_second_field = a_value_from_another_query
END
```

Or

```
SELECT a_field FROM a_table
WHERE
... 
AND
CASE a_value_from_another_query
WHEN NULL THEN a_second_field IS NULL
ELSE a_second_field = a_value_from_another_query
END
```

Or

```
SELECT a_field FROM a_table
WHERE
... 
AND
CASE NVL(a_value_from_another_query, 'x')
WHEN 'x' THEN a_second_field IS NULL
ELSE a_second_field = a_value_from_another_query
END
```

When `a_value_from_another_query IS NULL`, I want to add `a_second_field IS NULL` to my WHERE clause, when `a_value_from_another_query IS NOT NULL`, I want to add `a_second_field = a_value_from_another_query` to my WHERE clause.  How can I achieve this ?

Comment: You are going to have to clarify your thinking - and then re-explain.  You can use a `CASE expr WHEN value THEN ...` notation, or you can use `CASE WHEN expr THEN ...`, but your simple `CASE WHEN NULL THEN` notation will never evaluate the THEN because NULL will always evaluate to UNKNOWN, not TRUE.

Comment: `CASE WHEN field IS NULL ...`

Comment: Post more of the query if you want an answer about how to accomplish  conditional join criteria.

Comment: @todda.speot.is : this is what I used in my first example.

Comment: You mean `WHERE (field is null) OR (a_second_field = a_value_from_another_query)`?

Comment: @todda.speot.is : This seems to work too but i'm using the code from staticsan. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like you simply picked up the wrong tool from the toolbox.

Unless I have horribly misunderstood you, the following:

```
WHERE
    (a_value_from_another_query IS NULL AND a_second_field IS NULL)
  OR
    (a_value_from_another_query IS NOT NULL AND a_second_field = a_value_from_another_query)
```

... should so what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to use a CASE statement:

```
 1. CASE WHEN condition_1 THEN return_expr_1 
    [WHEN condition_2 THEN return_expr_2 ….] 
    [WHEN condition_n THEN return_expr_n ….] 
     [ELSE default] END 
 2. CASE expression WHEN value1 THEN result1
[WHEN value2 THEN result2
.....
ELSE resultn
]
END
```

In your selects, you are using instead a result, another expression. This isn't going to work. 
If you want to get your query working, you have to use the first case expression, and return a value, something like this:

```
SELECT a_field FROM a_table
WHERE
... 
AND nvl(a_second_field,'x')=(CASE WHEN a_value_from_another_query IS NULL THEN 'X' 
ELSE a_value_from_another_query END)
```